# How do you query text in a SQL Server XML column

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have a XML column in a SQL Server database table. It stores XML responses from a web service.

If that web service times out, it stores the actual text

> Error: Timed out waiting for a reply

It's actually storing that text in the XML column - and I can't seem to query it because I cannot compare a string to an XML value. Any ideas?

Comment: Just wrap it into a `<ErrorMsg> ..... </ErrorMsg>` XML wrapper?

Comment: Woah, scary... TIL that SQL Server doesn't actually confirm that data inserted into XML columns really is well-formed XML: `create table dbo.Test ( Foo xml ); insert dbo.Test (Foo) values (N'Error: Timed out waiting for a reply'); select * from dbo.Test;`

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - the XML datatype supports XML fragments. You don't have to give it a complete well formed document. In the case of a string like `'Error: Timed out waiting for a reply'` - this is just treated as a single text node. This is why the `XML PATH` string concatenation method works and doesn't complain that the output isn't valid XML

Answer (score 2):

A non empty string without any tags will be treated as a standalone text node in SQL Server.

So you can use `'text()[1]'` to get the first top level text node in the XML content and inspect that.

you can use `exist` if you want to exclude from consideration any content that is a mix of top level text nodes and elements.

```
SELECT *,
        your_col.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(8000)')
FROM t
WHERE your_col.exist('*') = 0 AND your_col.exist('text()') = 1
```